Recent movie (past ~2 years) involving girl falling in love with singer and scene with flying car
Within the past year (maybe two) I saw a trailer for a movie which was eventually released (this was at a Cineplex theatre).
From what I remember, the movie was about a girl (~18 years old?) living in a small town, and a big famous singer comes to town and falls in love with her. Things go well between them for a while, but then I think they go to shit. The movie was definitely not set in the present day, looked kind of like it was the 50s. The trailer was weird because it seemed to be interspersed with these crazy dream-sequence scenes.  The whole trailer seemed very surreal.
The thing I remember most vividly from the trailer is a dream-like scene in which the girl is driving this old car (a blue Chevy Bel Air, I think) which is flying through these thick purple clouds. There's a nerdy 50s looking young man wearing horn-rimmed glasses sitting next to her.
Can ANYONE tell me the name of this movie?
Release date: ~2013-2015
Genre: Drama or  comedy.  Possibly a musical, or at least containing musical elements.
Language: English

You forgot to mention the mutations... ;) Sounds like the bizarre musical Bang Bang Baby from 2014.

A small town teenager in the 1960s believes her dreams of becoming a famous singer will come true when her rock star idol gets stranded in town. But a leak in a nearby chemical plant that is believed to be causing mass mutations threatens to turn her dream into a nightmare. 

You can see them driving through the purple 'clouds' around 1:48 (and the horn-rimmed glasses guy around 1:07) in the trailer:




Absolutely right!  Amazing!  This question has been gnawing at me for weeks.  Thanks Walt!
